# Entering number in B column then finding number in A column

Tags: excel, vba

Sorry if the title is confusing.

I am working on an excel file that is a bit complicated.

Basically I need it to put a number in column B and have the macro find the same number in column A then copy everything (Including that number) above it.

I have tried using the find button but I cant seem to make it automatically find the number listed in column B in relation to column A.

This is the code I have tried so far:

```
Range("D1").Select
Cells.Find(What:="12", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:= _
    xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False _
    , SearchFormat:=False).Activate 
Range("A58").Select
Range(Selection, Cells(1)).Select
Selection.Copy
```

Comment: Two quick things: (1) Are the entries in column A unique? Or is it possible that there will be multiple entries in column A that will match the value entered in B? and (2) Can you show us some snippets of code you've tried already?

Comment: Sorry about the long wait, had a loooong week.
Column A is pretty much a pattern, everything is the same except for the number value.

 'code' 
Range("D1").Select
    Cells.Find(What:="12", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:= _
        xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False _
        , SearchFormat:=False).Activate
    Range("A58").Select
    Range(Selection, Cells(1)).Select
    Selection.Copy
'code'

Comment: What I am hoping for is a macro that lets the user enter a number and it finds that number and copies everything above that number. I cant seem to figure out how to let a user input a number and then have it search that number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I figured it out in my own way.
Column A has a pattern but the changing part is the number like so:

```
tim
car
1
tim
car
2
```

and so on.
In column B I made a formula =IF(A3=C1,"COPY","") 
C1 would have the number input from the user.
I then made a macro finding "COPY" in column B then offsetting it to the left and made it copy all the way to the top of the column.

It looked like this:

```
Sub Copy_1()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Range("B:B").Select
Selection.Find(What:="COPY", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=True, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Activate
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlUp)).Select
Selection.Copy
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```